# Organizing PDFs in pyPDF

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I have a question regarding Python and pyPdf.

What I am attempting to do, is create a PDF(obviously) and then have it ordered in a certain way. So that every time I run my script, it sorts it in a certain way for me, regardless of when the files were created.

If I have 7 files in my target folder, I want them ordered 7 4 3 2 1 6 5 in my final file, regardless of how they end up being placed in the folder.

The example I have below, basically does what I want, but doesn't order the PDFs as I want. It currently does it by date modified. Does that make much sense?

I'm fairly new to the Python game, and have no experience with pyPDF at all, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

```
def merge_pdfs(latest_dir):

startDir = latest_dir
os.chdir(startDir)
outFile = '%s_DepartmentalTaskList.pdf'%(time.strftime("%m%d%y"))

if os.path.exists('%s/%s'%(latest_dir, outFile)):
os.system('rm %s/%s'%(latest_dir, outFile))

fileList = os.listdir(startDir)
output = pyPdf.PdfFileWriter()

for item in fileList:
print 'item = %s'%item
    if os.path.splitext(item)[1].upper() == ".PDF":
        pdfDocument = os.path.join(startDir,item)
        input1 = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(file(pdfDocument, "rb"))
    for page in range(input1.getNumPages()):
        output.addPage(input1.getPage(page))


print 'outFile = %s'%outFile
outputStream = file(outFile, "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()

return '%s/%s'%(startDir, outFile)
```

Comment: How do you tell which file is which?

Comment: And what is the logic behind that ordering? I.e., if there were 8 files, how would I figure out the ordering?

Comment: Good questions!
The files would look like this:
091813lista
091813listb
091813listc
and so on.
The date would change based on today's date.

Answer (score 0):

os.listdir returns a list of filenames in arbitrary order, so you'll have to order its elements as you desire before you process them. The sort method of the list class will let you do so. Assuming your suffixes 'a', 'b', ... are the order you want, sorting by the date part of the filename and then the suffix will give what you want:

> fileList.sort( key=lambda fname: (fname[:6], fname[-1]) )

This sorts fileList in place.
Note that this is in Python 3.x style, where sort is passed a one-argument function returning the key to sort on (here, a compound key), rather than a two-argument comparison function. *However, the example shown above also works in Python 2.4 and up, which added the key function as a keyword argument.* If you're curious, see the Python 2.7 list.sort docs for further details, as well as the Sorting HOWTO (also in the docs).
If you're absolutely, positively sure that all files in the directory will have the same date, you can get by with:

> fileList.sort( key=lambda fname: fname[-1] )

If 'a', 'b', ... is NOT the order you want, then you'll need additional indirection, mapping those suffixes to the desired order -- say, a dictionary, `lookup_table`, mapping suffixes to ints in the order you want. In that case, you'd use `lookup_table[fname[-1]]` instead of just `fname[-1]`. However, I can't say much about how to construct `lookup_table`, based on what you've related (e.g. are there always 7 files?? it's unclear).

Comment: That makes sense. Because of my newness to Python, what would be the recommended way to do it in Python 2.7?

Comment: To answer above, there are always 7 files. The only thing about the file name that will change will be the date. For example, 091913_fileA, 092013_fileA, and so on.

Comment: The 7 files will also all have the same date in the folder.